# Why does Custom UITableViewCell causes an NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

i have created a custom `UITableViewCell`, but when I dequeue the cell, sometimes it throws an NSInvalidArgumentException:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell lblMonth]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aa7df0
```

Now, my custom `UITableViewCell` does have an attribute lblMonth, so I am confused why it is throwing this error. Below is the code I use to dequeue the cell:

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {   

        CustomCell *cell;

        cell = [(CustomCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil){

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"New_Phone" owner:nil options:nil];


            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


           CGFloat emival= emi;
            CGFloat curinterest = balarray[indexPath.row] * interset;
            if(indexPath.row == tenure){
                emival = balarray[indexPath.row-1] + curinterest;
            }
            CGFloat curamnt = emival - curinterest;
        balarray[indexPath.row]=balarray[indexPath.row]-curamnt;


           [[cell lblMonth]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row+1]];
           [[cell lblEMI]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", emival]];
           [[cell lblInterest]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", curinterest]];
           [[cell lblPrinicipal]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", curamnt]];
           [[cell lblBalance]setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", balarray[indexPath.row]]];

        return cell;
}
```

Please help me over this...Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in  following line of code:

```
cell = [(CustomCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

you should use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Because when you check for nil it will never be nil(it will not go in if case) and a UITableViewCell object is created not the custom cell object. But thats not what you want. You want to load cell from nib and dequeue it for reuse.

Comment: i'm facing with the other issue too..when ever i scroll the tableview values are getting changed..please help me over this....

Comment: as per the code the label values will be updated based on the indexPath.row. Isn't it expected behavior. Which values should not change?

Answer (score 0):

See Your Code you need to change FewLines with Given Lines and rest stays same.
This is Because you are making some Mistakes just Compare your code with below Code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 //below Line get cells if they Cells Exist.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//below Line Checking precrated Cells Exist
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [(CustomCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```